# Thymeleaf Option Without Selection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

From the controller, I have returned an object containing a list of objects. I want to display these list of objects in the dropdown with no pre-selection(or default value i.e. "Select Dish"), but dropdown is shown with pre-selected last value in the list.

Controller:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/createOrder")
public ModelAndView displayOrder(OrderFormDetails order) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("order", orderService.displayOrder());
    mav.setViewName("createOrder");
    return mav;
}
```

Model:

```
public class OrderFormDetails {

    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your name")
    private String name;

    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your address")
    private String address;

    private List < Dish > dishes;
```

View:

```
<select class="form-control" th:field="*{dishes}" id="dropOperator">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Sélect dish</option>
    <option th:each="dish, itemStat : *{dishes}" th:value="*{dishes[__${itemStat.index}__].id}" th:text="*{dishes[__${itemStat.index}__].title}">
    </option>
</select>
```

I have tried multiple tricks, but none of them worked. Thanks...

Comment: I've got 2 questions to you: why `displayOrder` accepts `OrderFormDetails` as a parameter and what does `orderService.displayOrder()` returns?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't want to mix possible options and selected option together within one field (as you apparently did). All you need to do is to decouple those things. Possible steps may be helpful:

1. Since `OrderFormDetails` acts like your form backing bean, it should contain a placeholder for selected value (`Dish.id`) instead of `List` with possible dishes. Change your `OrderFormDetails` to the following:

```
public class OrderFormDetails {

    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your name")
    private String name;

    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your address")
    private String address;

    private T selectedDish;

    // getters, setters, rest of the class omitted
```

...where `T` is the type assigned to `Dish.id` field.

2. Possible (selectable) dishes should be provided separately as a model attribute. Add following line to your `displayOrder` method:

```
mav.addObject("dishes", getDishes());
```

...where `getDishes()` returns `List<Dish>` containing all dishes being an option for an user.

3. Adjust your view to work with updated approach:

```
<select class="form-control" th:field="*{selectedDish}" id="dropOperator">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Sélect dish</option>
    <option th:each="dish : ${dishes}" th:value="${dish.id}" th:text="${dish.title}">
    </option>
</select>
```

That's all. Such an approach is also shown in [documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#dropdownlist-selectors) - `th:field` on `<select>` level refers to form backing bean's  field, whereas `<option>` elements are created out of separate collection provided as [model attribute](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#model-attributes).

Comment: Hey @oOXAam, was my answer helpful for you?